# Sharepoint Online REST: field property names in Item response JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Is there an exhaustive document of how (possibly user-added) field values are returned in [the Sharepoint REST ListItem GET endpoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListItemEndpoint)'s response?

Afaik, most field values are returned by its `EntityPropertyName` (ex: `abc` -> `{"abc": 123}`), except for Lookup fields and User fields which can be returned by `abc`, `abcId` and possibly `abcStringId`.

Are there any other cases that I'm missing? Are there any documents that clearly explain how the field values are formatted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such official documentation by Microsoft.

All Field values except Lookup Field and Person Or Group field are returned by its internal name (Name provided while creating field). You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

For Lookup and Person Or Group Fields, you need to expand those fields like given below:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle("DisplayNameOfList")/items?$select=Title,PersonOrGroupField/Id,LookupField/Id&$expand=PersonOrGroupField,LookupField
```

Answer (score 0):

No document about field property names in Json resonse.
A suggestion is that before you pass item meatadata in the Rest API, you could firstly check it in Browser like:

https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('MyList4')/items

[image]

For Lookup and Users field, append Id into the field name, for example, a lookup field named "testlookup", then pass into metadata in ajax, it should be testlookupId, hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: I'll have to work on a lot of lists, and unfortunately I don't have the luxury to check all of them. I've checked the responses of a handful of lists, and I discovered that Users fields return both "testlookupId" and "testlookupStringId", which totally surprised me. I'm wondering if there's any other (known) cases that a field returns multiple values or its property name differs from the field's EntityPropertyName.